# Query in DynamoDB contains list of values in KeyConditionExpression

Tags: arrays, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to do a SINGLE query in an AWS DynamoDB giving for multiple values and the scenario is something like that.
I want to query by giving a list of values. If the value exists in db(at a specific key, let's say 'mandatoryField'), then give me that value, this means at the end of filtering, I want get back only the values that were existing from my array input.

So, for these items in my db:

```
column: mandatoryField
        ---------------
1.      value1
2.      value2
3.      value3
4.      value4
```

And giving in my query command an array of `["value2", "value3334", "value7", "value1"]`, I want to receive back just the values that exists: `["value2", "value1"]`.

Tried this query in aws-cli, both with IN and CONTAINS func

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name testTable \
--key-condition-expression '#mandatoryField IN :values' \
--expression-attribute-names '{ "#mandatoryField": "mandatoryField" }' \
--expression-attribute-values '{
    ":values": { "SS": ["value2", "value3334", "value7", "value1"]}
}'
```

but received as I expected `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: IN`

Hope this is enough descriptive to achieve my goal by giving a QUERY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `--filter-expression` instead of `--key-condition-expression` using the AWS DynamoDB `scan` command.

Try this one:

```bash
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name testTable \
--filter-expression 'contains(:values, mandatoryField)' \
--expression-attribute-values '{
    ":values": { "SS": ["value2", "value3334", "value7", "value1"]}
}' \
--projection-expression 'mandatoryField'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :) but this does not fit my requirements, because your filtering-expression it s hardcoded for :value1 and value2, but, i will never know those values. not even value1 to value4

Comment: @User122333 I have updated my answer. Try this one.

Comment: Damn, I thought I tried this, maybe I misspelled. Anyway, it worked properly :) Be blessed and thanks a lot :D

Comment: This a `Scan` and is not what you should use, as its not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ExecuteStatement`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html) to provide you with `BatchQuery` like semantics.

```
aws dynamodb execute-statment \ 
--statement 'SELECT * FROM test-table WHERE mandatoryField IN ["value2", "value3334", "value7", "value1"]'
```

You can pass in up to 50 values for the partition key.